# Jade: Unexpected Identifier error on Ubuntu Machine - works on Mac

Tags: node.js, angularjs, macos, ubuntu, pug

The problem I have is that this works fine on my Mac machine but when migrating it to Ubuntu I get this error.

Here is my index.jade partial

```
.container-fluid
.row
    .jumbotron
        center
            h2 {{message}}

.container
    center 
       h2 Line Items
       table
        tr
            th File Name
            th File Type
            th ID
        tr
        tr(ng-repeat="infos in info")
            td {{infos.filename}}
            td {{infos.type}}
            td {{infos.id}}


.container
    form(name="metadata" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.email.$invalid }")
        div.row
            div.col-md-4(style="background-color:#eee;height:200px")
                center
                    h1 Resource Type
                    h3 Enter the type of file you are trying to upload
                    strong Sound Recording / Image
                div
                    center
                        select(name="type" ng-model="file.type") 
                            option Sound Recording
                            option Image
            div.col-md-4(style="background-color:#eee;height:200px")
                center
                h1 File Name
                h3 Enter the name of the file
                input(name="filename" ng-model="file.name" placeholder="filename.wav / image.jpg")
            div.col-md-4(style="background-color:#eee;height:200px")
                center
                    h1 ISRC
                    h3 Enter the ISRC Number
                    input(name="isrc" ng-model="file.isrc" placeholder="Your ID")
            button.btn.btn-primary(ng-click="save(file)") Submit
```

This give me the error:

```
Error: /home/me/dashboards/angular-express-seed/views/partials/index.jade:48
46|                 
47|
```

> 48|

Line 141: Unexpected identifier

I dont have anything on that line so there is possibly something wrong elsewhere in the document.

Also - running `jade ./views/partials/index.jade` Returns `rendered index.html`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the issue with the syntax

```
form(name="metadata" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.email.$invalid }")
```

It should be like below with comma

```
form(name="metadata", ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.email.$invalid }")
```

Applies to all tags with attributes. Not sure how it works on Mac because it should give the same error.

Comment: Man, thanks - This totally worked on my Mac and on another older instance that I had of Ubuntu.  Thanks again!